# How to add Eclipse Code Formatter file in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, code-formatting

**What I have:**

I have a customised code format (.xml) file that my team wants to use in our project. This file includes predefined coding styles and conventions for java file.

**What I want to do:**

Now I have to add this formatter as a **default code format**, so that when click the shortcut of *auto code format*, the entire file will be formatted according to the the conventions defined in the formatter.

Comment: as far as I know, you'll have to re-configure/re-type the format parameters inside AndroidStudio. That can be later exported for others on the team to use. It's in File -> Settings -> Editor

Comment: can I ask, why do you use a custom code format, and what good is it?

Comment: Well, some software developer groups or even some companies keep their own coding convensions and styling, so that the code will be neat & clean and readable for each and every developers of the team. Even it will be helpfull for new developer who join the team to collaborate. We know there is a default formatter allready exist in most of the modern IDEs. But some times (in my case) a developer team has to create its own convensions to keep there code maintainable.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After a long 2days effort I managed the steps to integrate **Eclipse Code Formatter** in **Android Studio**

Here I am sharing step by step procedures to integrate ***Eclipse Code Formatter*** in ***Android Studio***:

**Step 1:** Go to the Plugins Section of Android Studio.
The easiest way is Click Shift twice and type **Plugins**. Now go to the plugins menu.

[image]

**Step 2:** Click on Browse Repositories

[image]

**Step 3:** Type ***Eclipse Code Formatter*** in the search box. Select it and Click Install button in the right section

[image]

**Step 4:** After successful installation you can see a blue Eclipse Icon in the top pen

[image]

**Step 5:** Now go to *Settings >> Other Settings >> Eclipse Code formatter*

Click the **Browse** button.

[image]

**Step 6:** Then select the Code Format XML file

[image]

**Thats it**

Any time you click the code formatting command your full code will be formatted according to the code formatter.

**Code formatting shortcut:**

Windows:
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Linux:
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Start</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Mac:
 <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

In case anyone want to see how the code formatter xml looks, you can check [this one](https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-java-google-style.xml).

One of the mostly used code style used by google is [here](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml).

Comment: FYI: If you are using Ubuntu, you will need to change your system's Lock-Screen shortcut, which is also Ctrl-Alt-L by default.

Comment: You can also download and install a Save Actions plugin to format the code automatically: File > Settings > Other Settings > Save Actions

Comment: that is really helpful

Comment: where did u get the eclipse java formatter config file from?

Comment: how can i get **augmedix_android_dev.xml**? and there are no any selection for **Android Studio**

Comment: Still useful answer for Android Studio 3.4